# Non parametric test for ANOVA and coefficient of variation

Tags: anova, nonparametric, robust

1. Which is equivalent non parametric test for one way ANOVA ?
2. Is quartile coefficient of dispersion for non parametric test equivalent to coefficient of variation (COV)?
3. Among them which measures are more robust?

Comment: For 1: Have a look at the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance) for the Kruskal–Wallis test. For 3: robust in what sense? e.g. robust to what?

Comment: Thanks. Robust in statistical point of view; for example, parametric or non-parametric which is more robust?

Comment: There's more than one nonparametric test possible here. Robustness of what quantity, against what things? e.g. are you interested in effect of gross errors on $\alpha$, sensitivity to inliers of type II error, or what?

Comment: Basically I am interested robustness in terms of effect gross error. By the way, could you give some suggestion regards my second question?